# Axios выдает 400 ошибку. Все перепробовал

Tags: typescript, axios, nestjs, nextjs

Axios выдает 400 ошибку, подскажите пожалуйста что может быть.

Через postman все работает, а так нет

Вот сам конфиг аксиоса

```
import axios from "axios";
import { getCookie } from "cookies-next";

export const $authApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/api/",
  withCredentials: true,
});

const authInterceptor = (config: any) => {
  config.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${getCookie("token")}`;
  return config;
};

$authApi.interceptors.request.use(authInterceptor);
```

Это api запроса

```
import { $authApi } from "..";

const url = "auth";

export interface ILoginResponse {
  login: string;
  password: string;
}

export const authLoginApi = async (data: ILoginResponse) =>
  await $authApi.get(url + "/login", { data });
```

Это main.ts у Nestjs

```
import {ValidationPipe} from '@nestjs/common'
import {NestFactory} from '@nestjs/core'
import {DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule} from '@nestjs/swagger'
import {AppModule} from './app.module'
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
        cors: {
            origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
            credentials: true,
        },
    })

    app.setGlobalPrefix('api')
    app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({whitelist: true}))
    app.use(cookieParser())

    const config = new DocumentBuilder()
        .setTitle('Prisma Day - NestJS Prisma Workshop')
        .setDescription('Building a REST API with NestJS and Prisma')
        .setVersion('1.0')
        .build()

    const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config)

    SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document, {customSiteTitle: 'Prisma Day'})

    await app.listen(5000)
}
bootstrap()
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ, я просто отправлял вложенный объект.
Вот в чем была проблема

```
export const authLoginApi = async (data: ILoginResponse) =>
  await $authApi.post(url + "/login", data);
```